# Trello get the creation date of a card with the api

Tags: php, api, trello

I'm trying to obtain the creation date of a card without success and I don't see any fields with this information in the API. Is there anything else than the date of the last activity on the card?

Thanks

Comment: the data is descData?

Comment: I have either null or something like '"descData":{"emoji":{}}' in my cards descData.

Answer (score 4):

The full ID for every object has additional information embedded in it (cards, boards, lists), including the time it was created. The first 8 characters of the hexadecimal id (the first 4 bytes) represent a Unix timestamp, which can then be translated into a date.

For eg. If a board has an ID of 4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c

Taking the first 8 characters, we get: 4d5ea62f

Converted to a decimal from hexadecimal, the timestamp is: 1298048559

**PHP Example**

```
<?php
$cardID = '4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c';
$createdDate = date('r', hexdec( substr( $cardID , 0, 8 ) ) );
echo $createdDate;
?>
```

Comment: it may help someone :)

Comment: What timezone is it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find it by adding card_actions=all (or more specifically, card_actions=createCard) to the request url.